# What encoding does ZipArchive use to store file names inside the created archive?

Tags: php, encoding, php-ziparchive

I'm using the php ZipArchive class in order to generate a zip archive. I use the second parameter of the addFile method in order to set the name of the file in the archive (since the real file on disk has a different name). Some of the names must contain french accents (such as é). When I download the archive, the accents aren't correctly displayed in the file name. What encoding should I use for the file names ? (the application uses UTF-8)

Comment: Zip's a pretty old format, and predates Unicode. Older pre-2007 versions of the format most likely just use standard extended ascii. After '07, the new spec allowed for UTF-8. Check which file version you're generating.

Answer (score 9):

It is php bug #53948, see [official bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53948).

Suggested workaround (worked for me):

```
$zip->addFile($file, iconv("UTF-8", "CP852", $local_name));
```

Comment: my filename name is a utf 8 string and should be called "actualités"  but I'm getting "actualit├йs", any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Use DOS encoding. My file names has cyrillic characters, so I'm encoding the file names from `cp1251` (Windows) to `cp866` (DOS), upon passing the filename to `$zip->addFile()`.

**EDIT 2024-02-20:** here is what I'm doing to convert UTF-8 that contain Cyrillic characters into DOS chartable on Linux.

```
function utf8cp866($t) {
    if (stristr(PHP_OS, 'WIN')) return $t; // don't need to convert it on Windows.

    // fixing for Ukrainian "Ii" and quotes.
    return iconv('utf-8', 'cp866',
         str_replace('і', 'i', // Ukrainian i to latin. They look identically in unicode, but different characters. DOS cp866 table duesn’t support this character.
         str_replace('І', 'I',
         str_replace('"', '', // quotes can’t be unzipped with correct path :(
         str_replace('«', '', // these characters are not exist in DOS table
         str_replace('»', '',
         $t))))));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! How have you figured exactly what encodings to use?

Comment: I didn't figured it out, because I always knew it. :)) lol
Well, actually I used RAR since 1992 or 1993. RAR was originally written for DOS and later ported to Windows as WinRAR. So DOS code tables is native for RAR.

Comment: my filename name is a utf 8 string and should be called "actualités"  but I'm getting "actualit├йs", any idea ?

Comment: @famas23 this happens when you converting utf8 string into cp866. (Or utf8 string got converted into Russian cp866 — it's obvious by «й» character).

Comment: So what i need to do, iconv("UTF-8", "CP852", $local_name) ?

Comment: If your original code table is UTF-8 and target is cp852, then yes, it should work. I have edited answer and added example, how I converting UTF-8 filenames which contain Cyrillic characters into DOS Cyrillic char-table.

Answer (score 2):

Zip files don't have a specified encoding; the archive tool must guess (or assume) the encoding used. Try CP1252 first, then go from there.

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried ISO-8859-1, CP1252 and CP850 without success

Comment: What does the byte sequence of a filename look like, and what is it supposed to be in text?

Comment: my filename name is a utf 8 string and should be called "actualités"  but I'm getting "actualit├йs", any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the Windows system e.g French, internal zip of Windows use `IBM850` as encoding.